# GitLab CI: deploy multiple reveal.js presentations from one repository

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, reveal.js, gitlab-pages

This question is about how to deploy multiple reveal.js presentations on GitLab pages, originating from one repository.

### Summary

I'm quite new to reveal.js and playing around with integration to GitLab, deploying a presentation to GitLab pages. In my repo, I'm hosting my themes and presentations (all in one repo). I can deploy one presentation from one branch. Next goal is to host all/multiple (public) presentations at the same time with GitLab pages.

### Setup

- In my repository each presentation (reveal.js from [here](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js)) is sitting in one branch. There are also theme based branches that are just for keeping the record. For the example assume there are two presentations, sitting in `/2020/pres1` and `/2020/pres2`. (Setup was adapted from [Elmiko](https://notes.elmiko.dev/2017/10/08/how-i-use-revealjs.html) ).
- In the first presentation branch, a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file is sitting, which is deploying the first presentation to `username.gitlab.io/repo-name/` This is working fine.

  `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - mkdir .public
  - cp -r * .public
  - mv .public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - 2020/pres1
```

- To my understanding, adding a second, identical file, adapted for `pres2` it the `2020/pres2` branch would 'overwrite' the deployed first page.

### Question

What alterations have to be made on the yml files to achieve the following result?

- Presentations are hosted at `username.gitlab.io/repo-name/year/branch`.
- In this example the presentations would be reached at:

  - `username.gitlab.io/repo-name/2020/pres1` and
  - `username.gitlab.io/repo-name/2020/pres2`

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some trail and error, I came up with the following solution:

```
cache:
  paths:
    - public

pages:
  stage: deploy

  script:
  - mkdir .build
  - cp -r * .build/
  - mkdir -p public/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH/
  - rm -r public/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH/* # do delete possible stuff from old build
  - mv .build/* public/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH/
  artifacts:
    name: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"
    paths:
    - public
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596789/deploying-gitlab-pages-for-different-branches) helped to develop the solution shown.
Comments on possible flaws of this solution are appreciated. Not sure if it is a problem that the `only` statement was removed.

Comment: You might make use of a second stage "build" and pass artifacts from that to the pages job