# Multiple versions in self hosted Sphinx documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I am trying to build documentation for a self hosted GitLab project. This documentation will be hosted in GitLab pages, and will have different versions. Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596789/deploying-gitlab-pages-for-different-branches/58915486#58915486), I figured out how to host multiple versions on GitLab pages.

My problem now is how to access those versions.

I would like to use the ReadTheDocs theme, that seems to have been built with that in mind:

[image: rtd collapsible menu]

How can I access and modify that navigation menu? I haven't been able to find anything on the documentation.

(**Edit:** Just learned the name of that menu is *flyout*)

If this was not possible, I would like to somehow add a section on the left panel (like `html_sidebars` on the classic theme), since I already built a script to get links to the versions.

I really just need a way to add a section to the bar.

Comment: The flyout is not part of the RTD theme, but it is part of the RTD product. It is inserted for every theme, and there is no user control allowed to customize it, other than managing Versions and other attributes about your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My solution**

Since @Steve Piercy mentioned in a comment that there is no way to have the flyout in the RTD self-hosted theme, I attempted to personalise the left sidebar to add the version links.

Unlike the classic theme (with the `html_sidebars` I mentioned), there seems to be no way to configure what is shown. What you *can* do is [add customised javascript and css](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/adding-custom-css.html). So I created a small script that adds a new unordered list with the links to the versions at the top of the toc.

I would prefer to follow another approach, since it is hacky and it uses hardcoded css class names (that might change at any point), but it is the only thing that I could come up with and works alright.

If anyone needs more details on the solution, I can provide them.