# Deploying GitLab pages for different branches using Hugo framework?

Tags: git, gitlab-ci, pipeline, hugo, gitlab-pages

I'm using the Hugo framework to deploy GitLab pages. As described in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596789/deploying-gitlab-pages-for-different-branches), it seems to be possible to publish pages for multiple branches.

I tried to integrate the code provided in the post, but it doesn't work.

My original `gitlab-ci.yml` looks like:

```
image: registry.gitlab.com/pages/hugo/hugo_extended:latest

variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

before_script:
  - apk add --update --no-cache git

test:
  script:
  - hugo --gc --minify
  except:
  - master

pages:
  script:
  - hugo --gc --minify
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

Is it possible, to deploy pages for every branch when using hugo? What do i need to change to achieve this?

Comment: An alternative approach would be to use https://www.netlify.com/ to deploy your website. It is very easy to deploy multiple branches there (netlify works with GitHub, GitLab, etc.)

Comment: Here is the Hugo doc to deploy on netlify: https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-netlify/

Answer (score 0):

Below solution, from [GitLab Pages per branch : the no-compromise hack to serve preview pages](https://dev.to/zenika/gitlab-pages-preview-the-no-compromise-hack-to-serve-per-branch-pages-5599), works with Hugo or any generating framework.

You can then have these features :

- `main` content is exposed on `$CI_PAGES_URL` and the path is configurable with `$CURRENT_CONTENT_PATH`
- Per-branch preview content is exposed on `$CI_PAGES_URL/preview`, with a homepage to easily navigate to branches content
- Path to root preview folder is configurable with `$EPHEMERAL_BRANCHES_PATH` variable to hide preview content by obfuscation
- Generated pages are associated with environments to take advantage of auto-cleaning on branch deletion
- To avoid disturbing already existing environments, pages environment are placed under a `pages` folder
- If `main` content has not been generated in current cache, or if the cache has been deleted, an error is triggered, to avoid accidental deletion
- Deletion job can be triggered manually with any cache path as input, to clean outdated data
- Code can safely be added to an existing project pipeline without causing trouble with already existing jobs
- The `workflow:rules` can be deleted if you already have your own, or updated to match your flow
- The job must be named `pages` and the artifact must be a `public` folder to be deployed to GitLab Pages (or you can use the [pages:publish](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#pagespublish) keyword)

```yaml
workflow:
  rules: # disable tag pipelines and duplicate MR pipelines
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH

variables:
  EPHEMERAL_BRANCHES_PATH: preview # subpath to ephemeral branches content for preview, anything will work

pages:
  stage: build
  image: alpine:3.18
  cache:
    key: gitlab-pages
    paths: [public]
  before_script:
    # default available 'tree' app in alpine image does not work as intended
    - apk add tree
    # CURRENT_CONTENT_PATH is defined in rules, different between main branch and ephemeral branches
    - mkdir -p public/$CURRENT_CONTENT_PATH && ls public/$CURRENT_CONTENT_PATH/..
    - | # avoid deleting main branch content when cache has been erased
      if [ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" != "$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH" ] && [ ! -d public/$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH ]; then
        echo -e "\e[91;1m Unable to retrieve $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH generated files from cache ; please regenerate $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH files first\e[0m"
        exit 1
      fi
    - rm -rf public/$CURRENT_CONTENT_PATH || true # remove last version of current branch
  script:
    - ./generate-my-html.sh --output build-docs || true # insert here your code that generates documentation
    - mv --verbose build-docs public/$CURRENT_CONTENT_PATH
    - cd public/$EPHEMERAL_BRANCHES_PATH
    - tree -d -H '.' -L 1 --noreport --charset utf-8 -T "Versions" -o index.html # generate a root HTML listing all previews for easier access
  environment:
    name: pages/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    action: start
    url: $CI_PAGES_URL/$CURRENT_CONTENT_PATH
    on_stop: pages-clean-preview
  rules:
    # 'main branch' is exposed at GitLab Pages root
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      variables:
        CURRENT_CONTENT_PATH: "."
    # other (short-lived) branches generation are exposed in 'EPHEMERAL_BRANCHES_PATH/branch-name-sanitized' sub path
    - variables:
        CURRENT_CONTENT_PATH: $EPHEMERAL_BRANCHES_PATH/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  artifacts:
    paths: [public]
    expire_in: 1h

pages-clean-preview:
  stage: build
  image: alpine:3.18
  cache:
    key: gitlab-pages
    paths: [public]
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none # git files not available after branch deletion
    FOLDER_TO_DELETE: preview/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH # an indirection to allow arbirtraty deletion when launching this job
  script:
    - rm -rf public/$FOLDER_TO_DELETE
  environment:
    name: pages/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    action: stop
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: manual
      allow_failure: true
```