# How to use the project namespace in the environment URL of GitLab CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'd like to parameterize the environment URL of one of my GitLab CI job in a project which belongs to a subgroup.

If for example I have:

```
CI_PROJECT_PATH = mygroup/mysubgroup/myproject
CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE = mygroup/mysubgroup
CI_PROJECT_NAME = myproject
```

I'd like to have the URL to be something like `https://mygroup.gitlab.com/-/mysubgroup/myproject/-/jobs/12345/artifacts/public/index.html`.

But I cannot find a way to do this since [there is no predefined variable for the "sub-namespace"](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/350902) (here `mysubgroup`) and there is no variable substitution in `environment.url` as far as I can see.

I tried in my `gitlab-ci.yml` things like that:

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  image: bash:latest
  script:
    - export # print the available variables
  environment:
    name: test
    url: ${CI_SERVER_PROTOCOL}://${CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE}.${CI_PAGES_DOMAIN}/-/${CI_PROJECT_PATH#${CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE}/}/-/jobs/$CI_JOB_ID/artifacts/public/index.html
```

but the result is `https://mygroup.gitlab.com/-/${CI_PROJECT_PATH#myproject/}/-/jobs/12345/artifacts/public/index.html`.

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58402821/1064669
- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/350902

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`job:environment:url` is directly processed by gitlab, which does not support this kind of parameter expansion.

You'll need to use bash or a similar shell for this to work as intended:

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  image: bash:latest
  script:
    - echo "DEPLOY_URL=${CI_SERVER_PROTOCOL}://${CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE}.${CI_PAGES_DOMAIN}/-/${CI_PROJECT_PATH#${CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE}/}/-/jobs/$CI_JOB_ID/artifacts/public/index.html" > deploy.env
    - cat deploy.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: deploy.env
  environment:
    name: test
    url: $DEPLOY_URL
```

Based on the example given here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/#example-of-setting-dynamic-environment-urls

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to escape the inner curly braces like this: (`${CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE}` should become `` $`{CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE`} ``)

So the whole thing becomes:

`` url: ${CI_SERVER_PROTOCOL}://${CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE}.${CI_PAGES_DOMAIN}/-/${CI_PROJECT_PATH#$`{CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE`}/}/-/jobs/$CI_JOB_ID/artifacts/public/index.html ``